# Laravel 5.5 reset password without email field

Tags: laravel, reset-password

I've not come across a site that asks you to confirm your email address during a reset request, it seems like an unnecessary step, i want my users to be able to enter only password and password confirmation but no email.

I'm wondering if there is a solution for this, i'm thinking of a simple solution i will pass the user email address as parameter in the reset link like this

```
website.com/verify/{{reset_token}}/{{email}}
```

Then i will retrieve this email parameter and pass it to the hidden input value but i don't know how to attach the email address to the reset link.

If everyone knows any solution please let me know in the comments

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why would someone downvote my question ? Im sure my question is clear and respect all the rules, this is totally unfair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you are using the default Laravel routes which are...

```
// Don't forget to add the names to these routes. 
Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.forgot.get');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.forgot.post');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset.get');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset')->name('password.reset.post');
```

Then run

```
php artisan make:mail PasswordResetMail
```

Then in your **User** model, add this function

```
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
  Mail::send(new PasswordResetMail($this));
}
```

Then in **PasswordResetMail**, then in your constructor, you will get the user

```
public function __construct($user)
{
  $this->user = $user;
}
```

then pass the user to the blade view along with the token, and then in your blade file, add the route

```
route('password.reset.get', ['token' => $token, 'email' => urlencode($user->email)]);
```

This will pass the email as

```
?email=useremail%40gmail.com // Should be urlencoded
```

Then, in your reset form, add it as

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{ urldecode(request()->get('email')) }}" name="email">
```

Should be good to go :)

Comment: don't get where should I put this >>>> route('password.reset.get', ['token' => $token, 'email' => urlencode($user->email)]); <<<<< ?

Comment: @KirillOficerov In your mail's blade file. :)